# How to change default color of element in vue-bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

In my b-table i have a function that colors the rows based on a property :

```
<template>
    <b-table sticky-header="70vh" bordered striped
            :items="logs"
            :fields="fields"
            @row-clicked="showLogDetails"
            selectable
            select-mode="single"
            :tbody-tr-class="colorRowByCode"/>
</template>

methods: {
    colorRowByCode(item, type){
      if (!item || type !== 'row') return
      if(item.level === 'Critical') return 'table-danger'
      if(item.level === 'Warning') return 'table-warning'
      if(item.level === 'Error') return 'table-primary'
    }
  }
```

As you can see i return table-primary, let's say i wanna change this color to  #FFDEB9

I followed these documentations :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1395

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming

So i created a `custom.scss` file in my assets
and added this to my App.vue :

```
<style lang="scss">

  @import "assets/custom.scss";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
  @import '~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

</style>
```

in my custom.scss i tried multiple things out like :

```
$table-primary: #FFDEB9 !default;
table-primary{
    color: theme-colors(#FFDEB9);
}

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #FFDEB9,
  "table-primary": #FFDEB9
);
table-primary{
    color: #FFDEB9
}
```

without success, when i click on a row in the HTML explorer, all i see is that it has a class table-primary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTMTk.png)

How can i achieve this ? I really need differents colors for my table rows.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can have custom colored rows without changing the theme colors. Since you are giving the class name based on row, you can write CSS for the same.

Example : Lets say you have 3 types of row colors (row-danger, row-warning, row-primary)

```js
methods: {
    colorRowByCode(item, type){
      if (!item || type !== 'row') return
      if(item.level === 'Critical') return 'row-danger'
      if(item.level === 'Warning') return 'row-warning'
      if(item.level === 'Error') return 'row-primary'
    }
  }
```

Now in CSS you can add,

```css
<style lang="css">

.row-primary{
  background: #FFDEB9;
}

.row-danger{
  background: #FF0000;
}

.row-warning{
  background: #FF0101;
}

</style>
```

So basically you will be adding classes to your HTML using your method `colorRowByCode` and those classes will define the color for row as shown in CSS